MS Teams azure bot - verify request content
I need to verify that the requests we get to our webhook are from ms teams azure bot.
Does Teams Azure bot support any HMAC signature implementations?
Looks like I get a simple bearer (jwt) token.
What is the difference between my bot and these bots:
Verifying HMAC from Microsoft Teams custom Bot in PHP
Verifying HMAC from Microsoft Teams bot in Python Flask
Any other option?

Accepting / upvoting an answer serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" and upvote it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

According to the answer provided in this post, HMAC verification in Teams bot framework, found in Microsoft's Q&A forum, it is not supported. As you can see, I queried the respondent for an update since the original question was posted a year ago. You can follow that conversation or add details/questions of your own by visiting the above link. Hopefully, one of them will respond so you can get your (updated) answer.
As for the two links you posted, your suspicions are correct. Both of those code samples make use of webhooks which are supported.

Currently HMAC verification is not supported for bots. You can suggest this feature here: Microsoft Teams Community.
